# Get action and category of implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to catch an implicit intent from a third party library. It's not working, so I'd like to verify that I'm using the right action and category. I figured LogCat might display this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So, how do I display the action and category of an implicit intent?

Answer (score 0):

For catching implicit intent in your activity class please use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
    } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
    }
} else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
    }
} else {
    // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
}
```

If you want to understand further please refer to this link:

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html